# How can I chain ->makeHidden() when eager-loading a belongsToMany relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, nested, eager-loading

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to use `makeHidden()` when eager-loading? here is my code:

```php
        $work=Work::with([
            'work_category'=>function($query){
                $query->with(['companies'=>function($query){
                    $query->select('companies.id','companies.name');
                }]);
            },
            'prices',
        ])
        ->findOrFail($id);
```

Work has a `belongsTo('App\WorkCategory')` relationship, and  WorkCategory has a `belongsToMany('App\Company')` relationship through a pivot.

If I try to chain `->makeHidden('pivot')` on to `$query->select('companies.id','companies.name');` - I get a `BadMethodCall exception: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::makeHidden()`

Is there something I'm missing here?

This is the  code with the offending makeHidden() call

```php
        $work=Work::with([
            'work_category'=>function($query){
                $query->with(['companies'=>function($query){
                    $query->select('companies.id','companies.name')->makeHidden('pivot');
                }]);
            },
            'prices',
        ])
        ->findOrFail($id);
```

My temporary fix has been to add `protected $hidden=['pivot'];` to my Company model, however it would be nice to be able to access the pivot when I do need it, and use `$model->relation->makeHidden('attribute')` in my controllers to trim away extra data before sending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `makeHidden()` doesn't work on relationships in Laravel.  Not directly nor using dot notation on the related field.

You've touched upon one solution that I've used in the past, which is to use `select()` to limit to only the relationship's fields that you want within the subquery as a somewhat rough way to exclude your pivot:

```
$query->with(['companies'=>function($query){
     $query->select('id','name', 'something', 'something');
}]);
```

This works when the fields are limited.  But its a pain when you have a lot or are making many queries.

Another alternative is to do what you've done, and mark it protected on the model: `protected $hidden=['pivot'];`.  You then have *some* flexibility in various methods to use `->makeVisible('pivot');` on the fly to regain access to this pivot.

Comment: Thanks! Now that you've enlightened me about the `makeVisible()` method, it makes more sense to keep the pivot attribute hidden by default - as it usually only carries redundant information (model_a_id and model_b_id). So the workaround turns out to be the best solution.

Comment: If you ever want to use `makeHidden()`: `$work->work_category->companies->each->makeHidden('pivot');`

Comment: @Jonas - yes.  Or a foreach loop.  Just not really cleanly implemented in Laravel.  I think a little tighter to use makeVisible().